# Does the Process and Pool classes share the same workers?

Tags: python, process, multiprocess

I have a python script that is doing some map reduce-ish ETL. I am not originator of the code but working to analyze/diagnose its runtime for some improvements.

In the package, it uses a "Process":

```
worker = Process(target=grab_worker)

worker.start()
```

That does a perpectual FTP loop to extract new files from our CDN, can't include the FTP code but shouldn't be relevant for the question

Later in the code, we create an instance of a worker `Pool` which runs some asynch functions:

```
workerpool =  multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
# ...
resultobjs[k] = workerpool.apply_async(func, args=fargs)
```

Again, the underlying code therein should be irrelevant to question I think so not including code yet.

My question is, in Python, once I create the worker `Pool` will the workers there be "shared" with the `Process`?

In other words, if I first create 1 worker with process doing something, later in execution when I create workers with a pool class, when the loop returns and tries to run the function registered with the process, will it then use the previously created workers?

Or, instead, does it keep the "hot side hot and the cold side cold" by allowing each class instance to reference only the workers which it has spawned ( `Process` reuses its one worker previously created, and `Pool` continues to use its designated workers vs. `Process` using the workers generated by `Pool` ).

Answer (score 1):

The `mp.Process` knows nothing about the `mp.Pool`.
So the call to `mp.Process` will not somehow use a process spawned by `mp.Pool`.